# d3.js JSON read with file selection dialog box

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I can read file in the same folder than the script js, but not in **another folder**.

HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
<button class="mybutton" id="fileSelect">Select a file</button>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
or 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="my_script.js"></script>
</html>
```

D3.JS part:

```
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = '<input type="file" accept=".json">';
var fileInput = element.firstChild;

var fileSelect = document.getElementById("fileSelect");

fileInput.addEventListener('change', function() { // wait for file selection
    var file = fileInput.files[0];
    var file_name = file.name;
    // load the data 
    d3.json(file_name, function(error, graph) {
        do_things;
    }
});

fileSelect.addEventListener("click", function () {  // wait for click on "select a file" button
    fileInput.click();
});
```

**Where is my error?**

Thank you in advance

Comment: What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: Hi Ian the error was "graph not defined", but I have no more the error (I don't understand why it works now!). So the point is closed.